# Angular 2 npm js-sha1 import

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli

I've created angular-cli project. 
I want to add https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-sha1 so I used command.

```
npm install js-sha1 ---save
```

How should I import it then to be able to use it?
I'm trying to import it as:

```
import 'js-sha1';
```

But when I do:

```
 sha1('Message to hash');
```

it says it doesn't know what sha1 is.

Comment: are you using systemjs or angular-cli ?

Comment: same with me. i'm using angular-cli, any idea ?

Answer (score 10):

Try using

```
import * as sha1 from 'js-sha1';
```

for your import.